# XCode can't upload archive because of framework architecture

Tags: xcode, app-store, archive, ios-frameworks

I'm including an external framework in my xcode project. Everything works fine when I build from my laptop to my iphone. I've now archived my project and I'm trying to upload my archive to testflight. This is failing with the error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for \
MyApp.app/Frameworks/SomeSDK.framework contains unsupported \
architectures '[x86_64, i386]'."
```

What's going wrong? I've no idea how that framework was generated. Is there a setting to change to make things magically work?

Comment: Yes, it's a dupe. Frameworks are typically built to be universal. Hence, you need to strip out simulator slices (or any other slices which are not supported).